# why is my contract on ropsten invalid

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment

i did a sendrawTransaction on ropsten and got out of gas, despite contract is shown on etherscan. i sent again with enough gas and now contract address is 0x0.
What i did wrong ? 
here is the link to etherscan 
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x000ab857d04871672516292412e1e9ea887c652f
where transaction can be viewed

Comment: It appears to be a bug, you are better reporting it to etherscan so they can fix it.

Comment: i reported to etherscan and they said i should report to gitter channel of cpp-etherereum, what i have done

Comment: Do you have the code you are using to send the transaction? Can you try sending a similar transaction to another testnet? like rinkeby or a private testnet.

Comment: i have the code and will try to send the same tx to another testnet

Comment: by the way, here u can view tx code:https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x000ab857d04871672516292412e1e9ea887c652f

Comment: Without the source code that creates the transaction is hard to say anything concrete but in your failed transactions "to" is "0x0", and in the successful "to" is null.

Comment: send u source code soon, but another strange thing is, that a guy from etherscan could deploy my contract sucessfully on his account on myetherwallet.

Comment: here is the source code:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1E5NcokkMfXVMobLN1i36YN4h2Ubw7et-

Comment: I mean the code you use to create and send the transaction.

Comment: i created the transaction with ethkey and sent it using curl. Here is the link describing all steps:https://drive.google.com/file/d/14t0t6x5vkQHT9EEui-jbWWCaG9r15sLL/view?usp=sharing. Hope thats the things u needed

Comment: seems to be an ethkey issue. ethkey at the moment seems not to be able to sign a contract tx correctly

Answer (score 1):

it is indeed an ethkey issue, ethkey at the moment is not able to sign a contract tx correctly, using eth_sendTransaction, where eth itself signs the tx, a contract address is generated